# How to fix illegal character error in mex files

Tags: matlab, fortran, mex

I'm getting some error message when I try to compile the fortran code on matlab.

```
>> mex points.f
Warning: MATLAB FORTRAN MEX Files are now defaulting to -largeArrayDims and 8 byte integers.
     If you are building a FORTRAN S-Function, please recompile using the -compatibleArrayDims flag.
     You can find more about adapting code to use 64-bit array dimensions at:
     https://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/matlab_external/upgrading-mex-files-to-use-64-bit-api.html. 
Building with 'Intel Parallel Studio XE 2019 for Fortran with Microsoft Visual Studio 2017'.

Error using mex
C:\Users\Kinan\Desktop\Strathshare\Personal Folders\PhD\MATLABPERIDYNAMICS\points.f(44): error #5149: Illegal character in statement
label field  [r]
    re*8  dx, ral
----^

C:\Users\Kinan\Desktop\Strathshare\Personal Folders\PhD\MATLABPERIDYNAMICS\points.f(45): error #5149: Illegal character in statement
label field  [r]
    re*8 coordx, coordy, coordz
----^
>C:\Users\Kinan\Desktop\Strathshare\Personal Folders\PhD\MATLABPERIDYNAMICS\points.f(46): error #5149: Illegal character in statement
label field  [r]
    real*8 coord(totnode,3)
----^
```

The actual code is

```
#include "fintrf.h"
C======================================================================
C     points.f
C     Computational function that creates a cube of equdistant points
C     This is a MEX file for MATLAB.
C======================================================================


C     Gateway routine
      subroutine mexFunction(nlhs, plhs, nrhs, prhs)

C     Declarations
      implicit none

C     mexFunction arguments:
      mwPointer plhs(*), prhs(*)
      integer nlhs, nrhs

C     Function declarations:
      mwPointer mxGetDoubles

      mwPointer mxCreateDoubleMatrix
      integer mxIsNumeric
      mwPointer mxGetM, mxGetN



C     Pointers to input/output mxArrays:
      mwPointer x_ptr, y_ptr




C     Array information:
      mwPointer mrows, ncols
      mwSize size






C     Arguments for computational routine:
    real*8  dx, r
    real*8 coordx, coordy, coordz 
    real*8 coord(totnode,3)
    real*8 ndivx, ndivy, ndivz
    integer i, j, k





C     Get the size of the input array.
      mrows = mxGetM(prhs(1))
      ncols = mxGetN(prhs(1))
      size = mrows*ncols


 MX_HAS_INTERLEAVED_COMPLEX
      x_ptr = mxGetDoubles(prhs(1))

C     Create matrix for the return argument.
      plhs(1) = mxCreateDoubleMatrix(29791,3,0)
      y_ptr = mxGetDoubles(plhs(1))


      call points(coord,r,dx,ndivx,ndivy,ndivz)




C     Load the data into y_ptr, which is the output to MATLAB.
      call mxCopyReal8ToPtr(y_output,y_ptr,size) 




      return
      end



C-----------------------------------------------------------------------
C     Computational routine

      subroutine points(coord,r,dx,ndivx,ndivy,ndivz)


C     Arguments for computational routine:
      real*8  dx, r, coordx, coordy, coordz 
    real*8 coord(totnode,3), ndivx, ndivy, ndivz
    integer i, j, k


do i = 1,ndivx
    do j = 1,ndivy
        do k = 1,ndivz
            coordx = -1.0d0 / 2.0d0 * r + (dx / 2.0d0) + (i - 1) * dx
            coordy = -1.0d0 / 2.0d0 * r + (dx / 2.0d0) + (j - 1) * dx
            coordz = -1.0d0 / 2.0d0 * r + (dx / 2.0d0) + (k - 1) * dx
            nnum = nnum + 1
            coord(nnum,1) = coordx
            coord(nnum,2) = coordy
            coord(nnum,3) = coordz

        enddo        
    enddo
enddo

      return
      end
```

I have a few for loops I need to do this for so if I can get a working template it would help a lot.

Sorry I tried to add more of  the error message but it said I had too much code

Comment: Yes I know it is strange. Yeah it's the code I complied. I was wondering if it had something to do with this version  warning at the beginning but I don't really understand if that makes a difference.

Comment: What is `MX_HAS_INTERLEAVED_COMPLEX` ? Is it stackoverflow copy error?

Comment: MX_HAS_INTERLEAVED_COMPLEX is an error it should have a comment Infront of it. I'll upload more of the error message and corrected code tonight

Comment: Why some lines doesn't start on 8-th column ? Is it a stackoverflow copy error or is it the actual source file ?

Comment: I agree with PTRK ... you've got fixed format source code but you have code in columns 1-6 which is reserved for labels and continuation, hence the error.  You need to fix your source code and indent all code so that it is beyond column 6. (Maybe this has tabs instead of spacing?)

Answer (score 0):

I managed to MEX the code, but there are too many errors...

For suppressing the warning about `largeArrayDims` you can execute:
`warning('Off', 'MATLAB:mex:FortranLargeArrayDimsWarn_link');`

Note: Your Fortran code applies `MX_HAS_INTERLEAVED_COMPLEX`, so you need to add `-2018a` flag to the `mex` command.
I could not find a way to avoid the warning when using `-2018a` flag.

MEX command line uses `-2018a` flag:
`mex -R2018a points.F`

I had to make too many modifications to your code, in order to pass compilation:
I added spaces to the beginning of the lines.
I removed `MX_HAS_INTERLEAVED_COMPLEX`.
I didn't know what to do with `totnode`, so I replaced it with the value `100`.
I didn't know what to do with `y_output`, so I replaced it with `coord`.

Here is your modified code that passes compilation:

```
#include "fintrf.h"
C======================================================================
C     points.f
C     Computational function that creates a cube of equdistant points
C     This is a MEX file for MATLAB.
C======================================================================


C     Gateway routine
      subroutine mexFunction(nlhs, plhs, nrhs, prhs)

C     Declarations
      implicit none

C     mexFunction arguments:
      mwPointer plhs(*), prhs(*)
      integer nlhs, nrhs

C     Function declarations:
      mwPointer mxGetDoubles

      mwPointer mxCreateDoubleMatrix
      integer mxIsNumeric
      mwPointer mxGetM, mxGetN



C     Pointers to input/output mxArrays:
      mwPointer x_ptr, y_ptr

C     Array information:
      mwPointer mrows, ncols
      mwSize size



C     Arguments for computational routine:

      real*8  dx, r
      real*8 coordx, coordy, coordz 

C     What is totnode???
C     real*8 coord(totnode,3)
      real*8 coord(100,3)
      real*8 ndivx, ndivy, ndivz
      integer i, j, k





C     Get the size of the input array.
      mrows = mxGetM(prhs(1))
      ncols = mxGetN(prhs(1))
      size = mrows*ncols


C MX_HAS_INTERLEAVED_COMPLEX
      x_ptr = mxGetDoubles(prhs(1))

C     Create matrix for the return argument.
      plhs(1) = mxCreateDoubleMatrix(29791,3,0)
      y_ptr = mxGetDoubles(plhs(1))


      call points(coord,r,dx,ndivx,ndivy,ndivz)




C     Load the data into y_ptr, which is the output to MATLAB.
C     call mxCopyReal8ToPtr(y_output,y_ptr,size)    What is y_output???
      call mxCopyReal8ToPtr(coord,y_ptr,size)





      return
      end



C-----------------------------------------------------------------------
C     Computational routine

      subroutine points(coord,r,dx,ndivx,ndivy,ndivz)


C     Arguments for computational routine:
      real*8 dx, r, coordx, coordy, coordz
C     What is totnode???      
C     real*8 coord(totnode,3), ndivx, ndivy, ndivz
      real*8 coord(100,3), ndivx, ndivy, ndivz
      integer i, j, k


      do i = 1,ndivx
        do j = 1,ndivy
          do k = 1,ndivz
            coordx = -1.0d0 / 2.0d0 * r + (dx / 2.0d0) + (i - 1) * dx
            coordy = -1.0d0 / 2.0d0 * r + (dx / 2.0d0) + (j - 1) * dx
            coordz = -1.0d0 / 2.0d0 * r + (dx / 2.0d0) + (k - 1) * dx
            nnum = nnum + 1
            coord(nnum,1) = coordx
            coord(nnum,2) = coordy
            coord(nnum,3) = coordz

          enddo
        enddo
      enddo

      return
      end
```

I hope it helps you continue your development.

Comment: Thank you that is a huge help. totnode is an input which is the total number of nodes I've tried to add it in by doing

      real*8  dx, r
      real*8 coordx, coordy, coordz, totnode 

but I get 
```
error #6219: This variable, used in a
specification expression, must be a dummy argument, a COMMON block object, or an object accessible through host or use association.
[TOTNODE]
      real*8 coordx, coordy, coordz, totnode
-------------------------------------^
compilation aborted for C:\Users\Kinan\Desktop\Strathshare\Personal Folders\PhD\MATLABPERIDYNAMICS\points.f (code 1) ```

Comment: You can't implement the complete code, and then start checking. Implement your code starting from a small portion, test it, extend it, and test again. I recommend that you start the testing in Visual Studio and make the MEX interface when your code is tested.

Comment: For testing you code, you can create the input using Matlab, save the input data to files, and read the input in Fortran (from files)... Store the Fortran output to file, read the output (from file) in Matlab, and check the output correctness in Matlab. For checking the output, you may need to implement the kernel function in Matlab. It's sound like a lot of work, but it is much faster this way...

Comment: @kbez You get this error because you're declaring a assumed-size array were the lower extent is not a constant or a dummy argument (it's not even declared *at all*).

Comment: @PTRK sorry but I have no idea what any of that means.

Comment: @kbez I recommend you to read the beginning of [this blog](https://thinkingeek.com/2017/01/14/gfortran-array-descriptor/). You didnt specify `integer totnode` in the list of parameter and you didn't add `totnode` in the argument list of `mexFunction` and `points`. Since coord use totnode as the first extent, it must be declared. Hence the error